# Throttling bandwidth for Apache on an Xserve (Mac OSX Server 10.5.8)

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, xserve, throttling

I was wondering if anybody has any solutions for throttling bandwidth on an Xserve (running Apache 2); I'm trying to use mod_bw (http://ivn.cl/category/apache/#bandwidth), but have been running into problems.  I can build the right module using apxs, but I run into problems when I try to restart Apache (it says that mod_bw.so is compiled for the wrong architecture).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do bandwidth throttling using the dummynet feature of the firewall (instructions at [Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736) and [AFP548](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20060214081244545), but since these are just tied to TCP port numbers, they can't distinguish between different virtual hosts, client connections, etc.

You're probably better off fixing the architecture mismatch.  Run `file /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_bw.so` to see what architecture(s) the module was built for, and `file /usr/sbin/httpd` to see what httpd is built for (under 10.6, it should be X86_64, i386, and ppc).  To control what architecture(s) the module is built for, I think you can just add -arch flags to be passed to the compiler and linker, e.g.

```
apxs -Wc,"-arch x86_64" -Wc,"-arch i386" -Wc,"-arch ppc" -Wl,"-arch x86_64" -Wl,"-arch i386" -Wl,"-arch ppc" ...
```

It's probably best to match the architectures httpd is compiled for, but only really necessary to include whatever mode it's actually running in; to find this out, you can view it in Activity Monitor.